# Python Logistic Regression Future Prediction

Tags: python, logistic-regression

What would be a way to make something take data points, plot them, and show the predicted future, as such:

[image]

I tried all current algorithms available and noticed that everything is a straight (best fit) line - how does this site do it?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this site](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-methods-in-python-cheat-sheet/) - There are many **time-series forecasting** methods to choose from...

```
- Autoregression (AR)
- Moving Average (MA)
- Autoregressive Moving Average (ARMA)
- Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average (ARIMA)
- Seasonal Autoregressive Integrated Moving-Average (SARIMA)
- Seasonal Autoregressive Integrated Moving-Average with Exogenous Regressors (SARIMAX)
- Vector Autoregression (VAR)
- Vector Autoregression Moving-Average (VARMA)
- Vector Autoregression Moving-Average with Exogenous Regressors (VARMAX)
- Simple Exponential Smoothing (SES)
- Holt Winter’s Exponential Smoothing (HWES)
```

And according to [this site](https://www.askpython.com/python/python-plotting-and-graph-libraries), many different ways to plot it:

```
Matplotlib: Plots graphs easily on all applications using its API.
Seaborn:    Versatile library based on matplotlib that allows comparison between multiple variables.
ggplot:     Produces domain-specific visualizations
Bokeh:      Preferred libraries for real-time streaming and data.
Plotly:     Allows very interactive graphs with the help of JS.
```

Now I don't anticipate that you would want every possible permutation or combination of the methods above, so I would recommend doing some research on some of these, and deciding the one that best suits your needs and your goals.

Comment: None of these give the result I would like them to. A simple array, `[100, 100, 105, 105]` should predict a slow increase in value, but all algorithms keep 105 as a constant, likely due to averaging.